# OSError: [Errno 9] Bad file descriptor with open() and write()

Tags: python

I watched a lot of videos and resolution of the problem: OSError: [Errno 9] Bad file descriptor when I want to use open() or F.write() but nothing works more the open doesn't create a file :

```
with open('info2.txt', 'w+') as f:
            f.write("Test")
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wBDtk.png)